# Rewriting LinkedList addAll method

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

For school I am working on a project where I am rewriting LinkedList. My class is a singularly linked list called StringLinkedList (can only hold Strings at the moment). I was writing the addAll method but something is wrong with my code. It works at the beginning and ends of lists but I can't figure out why it wont work when inserting into the middle of the list

here is the method and related methods

```
    public boolean addAll( int index, StringLinkedList strLis ) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        if (strLis.size == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (this.size() == 0) {
            head = strLis.head;
        }
        else if (index == 0) {
            strLis.nodeGet(size - 1).next = head;
            head = strLis.head;
        }
        else if (index == size) {
            nodeGet(size - 1).next = strLis.head;
        }
        else {
            Node prev = nodeGet(index - 1);
            Node succ = prev.next;
            
            prev.next = strLis.head;
            strLis.nodeGet(size - 1).next = succ;
        }
        
        size += strLis.size();
        
        return true;
    }
```

here is my Node class (embedded in the StringLinkedList class)

```
class Node {
        private Object data;
        private Node next;

        /**
         * This builds a Node instance
         * This instance of Node will initially contain 
         * the data passed via the parameter
         * and have the pointer to the next node set to null
         * @param data data that will be held in the node
         */
        public Node(Object data) {
            this(data, null);
        }

        /**
         * This builds a Node instance
         * This instance of Node will initially contain 
         * the data passed via the parameter
         * and have the pointer to the next node set to the Node parameter
         * @param data data to be held in node
         * @param next reference to next node in list
         */
        public Node(Object data, Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
```

Here is my nodeGet method

```
private Node nodeGet(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Node temp = head;

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

Also, I am aware that I am only copying the references into the .next fields which you are usually not supposed to do. Usually you would instantiate a new node at add it to the list. My teacher says that is not necessary for the functionality of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> something is wrong with my code

Consider including the test cases that fail and the generated error mesages instead of the above.

This line has a bug:

```
strLis.nodeGet(size - 1).next = succ;
```

`size` holds the size of the source list not the size of the `strLis`. Replace it with:

```
strLis.nodeGet(strLis.size() - 1).next = succ;
```

Assuming `StringLinkedList` has a `size()` method which should be trivial to add if not already present.

And it should at least solve the issue of your question. Again, the only way to make sure the code is working is to throw as many edge test cases at it as you can.

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue. Kind of embarrassing that I was using the wrong size